# Why C# thread stop working automatically

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread in my program which runs the timer function for example

```
Thread PopMonitoringThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PopMonitoring));  
PopMonitoringThread.Start();

public static void PopMonitoring()
{
    TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(Tick);
    Timer stateTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000);
}

//Timer method
static public void Tick(Object stateInfo)
{
    try
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.BatchingMode > 0)
        {
            if (batchTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now) < TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                batchTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Properties.Settings.Default.BatchingMode);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
                Process();
                Console.WriteLine("Batch Process Run");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Pop3 Monitoring start after: {0}", batchTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

When I comment out my Process() method it works fine every second my timer interation works
but when I uncomment Process method from my Tick method timer stops working ie Tick method stops working.
Process method code is working perfect mean there are no compile and runtime errors.

Comment: What you're doing in `Process`?

Comment: My Process method read mail from pop3 gmail then filter and send httpwebrequest to my mvc3 application

Comment: process could take more than the interval you've set. since you are hitting external service, consider increasing the polling freq.

Comment: Yes, That is also i have checked my process method needs 2 min to run and i have set my timer method 5 min then also it not working properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread you are creating stops almost instantly, whether or not you're calling `Process()`.
All you are doing in the thread, is starting a timer. the actual `Tick` method is being executed in a background thread from the [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

Now, at some point your `stateTimer` will be garbage collected, because it has fallen out of scope. At this point the timer will no longer be triggered. Most likely, this garbage collection is happening much sooner when you are calling `Process()`

You can test it by calling `GC.Collect()` in your `Tick` method. You'll see it stops after one or two ticks.

To fix it, make `stateTimer` a member variable. Lose the `Thread` stuff:

```
class Program
{
    private static Timer _stateTimer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _stateTimer = new Timer(Tick, null, 0, 1000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static public void Tick(Object stateInfo)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

PS: I assume this code is because you've been experimenting, but if you want to rethrow an exception you've caught, you should use `throw;` without any parameters: see [this Blog article](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2013/02/21/Preserving-Stack-Trace.aspx) for a brief explanation.

Comment: Gr8 superb thanks...  from last 2 days i am trying to solve this ...     Thank u very much